# Erro ao realizar login gmail - Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain

Tags: javascript, html, google, login, gmail

Estou tentando implementar o login pelo gmail em meu website, entretanto, o mesmo da a seguinte tela de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi em algumas outras perguntas que o problema seria pelo link estar com ip, ao invés de localhost ou um dominio de fato ex: mydomain.com.br

Alguém sabe o que pode ser feito, por favor?

Comment: Esse é um ip fixo?

Comment: Ele é gerado quando dou http-server pelo prompt do node.

Comment: Assim pelo pouco que sei, esse ip é exclusivo para rede privada... Então quando você fala "meu site" você quer dizer que está fazendo esta tentativa localmente ou você tem um site no ar, com ip ou domínio válido?

Answer (score 1):

O problema realmente era o link em ip fixo. Passei o mesmo para um dominio e funcionou normal.